# Equivalent of protractor's isDisplayed

Tags: javascript, selenium, testing, protractor, chai

I want to assert that an element exists on a page. It is possible to check that in protractor like that:

```
expect(element(by.id('button')).isDisplayed()).to.eventually.be.true
```

What would be the equivalent in Selenium? I tried

```
expect(driver.findElement(By.id('button')).isDisplayed()).to.be.true
```

But I get the error `NoSuchElementError: Unable to locate element: *[id="button"]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So when calling `driver.findElement` you are looking for the WebElement on the page. If it does not appear in the DOM at the time of the request, it will return a `NoSuchElementError`.

You could alternatively, do a driver.wait. The following is a selenium-webdriver snippet.

```
driver.wait(() => {
  return driver.findElement(By.id('button')).then(() => {
    return true;
  }).catch(() => {
    return false;
  });
}, 5000);

expect(await driver.findElement(By.id('button')).isDisplayed()).toBeTruthy();
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help.